# Single column tikz text box

Tags: tikz-pgf, two-column

How shall I change the `mybox` style defined below such that it fits in the second column?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, very thick, rectangle, rounded corners, inner ysep=5pt, inner xsep=5pt]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-4]

\vspace{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){
\begin{minipage}{.96\textwidth}
\textbf{lipsum[2-4] -} In this example, lipsum package is used to print dummy text below chapter title. lipsum[2-4] prints lorem ipsum text from paragraph 2 to paragraph 4.
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Reduce the width of `minipage`. Say, change `0.96\textwidth` to `0.5\textwidth` or to `\linewidth`.

Comment: @nidhin Great, thanks! Do you mind posting as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mybox` is flowing out because the width you provided for `minipage`, `0.96\textwidth`, is larger than the `linewidth` (=0.5*`\textwidth`). Reduce the width to `0.5*\textwidth` or below. Alternatively, use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, very thick, rectangle, rounded corners, inner ysep=5pt, inner xsep=5pt]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-4]

\vspace{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){
\begin{minipage}{.96\linewidth}
\textbf{lipsum[2-4] -} In this example, lipsum package is used to print dummy text below chapter title. lipsum[2-4] prints lorem ipsum text from paragraph 2 to paragraph 4.
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use a `tcolorbox` instead of `TikZ` nodes:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white, size=fbox, colframe=black, boxrule=1.2pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{mybox}
\textbf{lipsum[2-4] -} In this example, lipsum package is used to print dummy text below chapter title. lipsum[2-4] prints lorem ipsum text from paragraph 2 to paragraph 4.
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]